# Constructor or Object Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript (started learning it this week). I've completed the CodeCademy course (actually just Objects 1 && 2 parts, rest was boring). I thought I learned prototypal inheritance with constructors, but than I've started watching [Douglas Crockford: Advanced JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg)

Right at the beginning of the video, he mentions 2 types of inheritance, and I've realized, everything I thought I knew, I don't know. So I've started playing with Chrome JavaScript console and tried to do something using both inheritance models.

```
//create constructor
function MyParent(){ 
    this.name = "joe";
    this.sayHi = function(){ 
        console.log(this.name); 
    }
}

//create child object and inherit from parent
var myChild1 = new MyParent();
myChild1.name
"joe"
myChild1.sayHi()
joe

//add method to MyParent, so it can be accessed from myChild1
MyParent.prototype.sayBye = function(){ console.log("bye");}

myChild1.sayBye()
bye

//create another constructor
function MyParent2(){
    this.sayHi = function(){ 
        console.log("hi"); 
    }
}

//make it inherit from MyParent, overwriting sayHi if object is instance of MyParent2
MyParent2.prototype = new MyParent();

//overwrote sayHi
var myChild11 = new MyParent2(); 
myChild11.sayHi();
hi

//still same as MyParent as its not overwriten in MyParent2
myChild11.name
"joe"
```

Than I've tried to do the same thing using Object.create:

```
//create an object
 var myParent = { 
    name : "joe",
    sayHi : function(){ 
        console.log(this.name) 
    } 
};

//it works
myParent.sayHi()
joe

//create child object
var myChild = Object.create(myParent);
myChild.sayHi()
joe

//add bye method to myChild
myChild.sayBye = function(){ console.log("bye"); }
myChild.sayBye();
bye

//add bye method to myParent - does not overwrite child's bye
myParent.sayBye = function(){ console.log("bye2"); }

//however adding sayBye2 to parent, becomes available on already created child
myParent.sayBye2 = function(){ console.log("bye2"); }
myChild.sayBye2();
bye2
//but its the parent property
myChild.hasOwnProperty("sayBye2")
false

//could make million objects inherit from each other vertically or horizontally
var myChild2 = Object.create(myChild);
myChild2.name
"joe"
```

So far, just by first impression, I do like both models, maybe I slightly prefer the latter. It seems to be more expressive and powerful.

I've done some search on the `vs.` topic, but couldn't find a good article, that would explain pros and cons of each approach (other than latter is supported by newer browsers only, but there is a simple workaround). Rest of the posts I found were just tl: dr; and somewhat boring.

So my question is, which type of inheritance should I go with. Are there any perks associated with either? Any major cons for either? Can you mixin both? (eg. I know you can pass object as argument into `new Constructor()`))

Thanks

EDIT:
Looking at trick to create Object.create() alternative if browser doesn't support it, I realized how simple the hack is. It is basically creating an empty constructor, assigning parent object as its prototype and returning the built constructor as new object. What a neat hack!

```
if(typeof Object.create !== "function") { Object.create = function (o) { function F() {}; F.prototype = o; return new F(); }; }
```

But what are the implications? Any gotchas to be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ways are **equally powerful**. Some says that you are not a real JavaScript master if you do not embrace the *pure* prototypal approach, but really everything is still just **prototypal inheritance** and it's a matter of style.

Personnaly, I prefer using a classical approach and make use of the `new` keyword together with a `constructor` function.

Why?

- The classical model is very well-know.
- I don't have to implement an `init` function on my objects only to do what a `constructor` does already. As you probably noticed, the *pure* prototypal approach leaves you without a `constructor` so you will have to implement an initialization function (generally called `init`) if you need to run some initialization logic for newly created objects.

However, I find that the *pure* prototypal approach is a bit less verbose and might be easier to understand for programmers without a strong background with languages implementing classical inheritance.

By the way, one thing you should **avoid** with the classical model is to inherit using the `new` keyword like you are doing above because you are running the parent `constructor` logic unnecessary and it could potentially have undesirable side-effects.

You should be using `Object.create` like below:

```
function A(val) { this.val = val; }
A.prototype.alertVal = function () { alert(this.val); };

function B(val) {
    A.call(this, val); //call parent constructor
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype); //inherit from A
var b = new B('test');
b.alertVal(); //test
```

At the end, it's all a matter of taste and I respect **both ways**. Maybe someone else will want to improve this answer with some real advantages/disadvantages, but I cannot find any.

Comment: How does A.apply method work? What does it do in this case exactly?

Comment: Is it invoking A constructor, and passing this (scope of B) and arguments (again, of B) to A?

Comment: @JanNetherdrake I was writing something, but you got it, it makes sure that the `A` constructor logic gets applied on the newly created instance of `B` by setting the context object (the object to wich `this` points to). If you would have called `A();`, the context object would have been `window` and that's not what you want. Now, for the differences between `apply` and `call`, I suggest you go read about it ;)

I updated the example so that it makes a bit more sense to call the parent's constructor.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with apply/call tho. Is the point of using apply/call the fact, that you are passing 'this' of the outer to the invoked function? I suppose if you had 2 methods, inner and outer (inner being sort of a closure), if you hadn't used 'apply', you would need to put 'this' in a variable, so it could be scoped to the closure, else it would be unacessible, since the closure would have own 'this'? Correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake, To make it simple, unless `new`, `call` or `apply` is used when calling a function, `this` will point to the `object` on wich the function was invoked (the object on the left side of the `.`) in `myObject.someFunction();`. However, if `someFunction();` is invoked this way, it's the same as doing `window.someFunction();`, so `this` will point to `window`. Now, with the above case, we want the `A` function to have it's context object (`this`) set to the new `B` instance. Since calling `A(val);` would result in `this` pointing to `window`, we have to use `A.apply(this, val);`.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake, A `closure` can be an alternative way of accessing an object declared outside a specific `function`. However, to create a closure over a variable, the function has to be declared in the same (or lower) `scope` as that variable. In the case above, the `A` function is declared outside the function `B`, therefore we cannot use closures in that case. *Please note that using closures will not  change the context object `this` in any way.*

Comment: I now understood the concept of 'this' correctly. Thanks for explaining it to me. 

By closure I meant something that is not in your example. For example, returning a function from function would be a closure. If I invoke 'this' within such closure, would it be the same 'this' as in main function?

eg. function main(){ /* this */ return { ok : function(){ return this; }; } } Are 'this' in main and 'this' in 'ok' same?

Comment: @JanNetherdrake, No, closures have nothing to do with `this` and they don't affect the way `this` works in any ways. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0):

Constructing objects with `new` was pronounced evil, because you can forget to use it and then whatever properties you add to `this` will end up added to the global object. For this reason I am in for the second approach.

One other thing I have learnt is that you should not try to apply "classical" OOD to JavaScript. It has its own way that should be understood and it is quite nice in fact. I think most of object programming problems in JavaScript come from attempts to stretch notion of "class" onto JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, Crockford said the reason why constructor names start with capital letter is to try and remind us to use 'new'. I am very open to different, this is why I'm quite enjoying JS. So I will not try and think like Java in JS.