# Angular js, constructor or object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, constructor

In AngularJS, is it more advisable to return a `constructor` or an `object`, of which we might then create new instances as needed?

As a pure JavaScript issue, this has been discussed [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871206/constructor-or-object-inheritance-in-javascript). I want to understand this from a AngularJS best practices perspective, for two reasons:

- performance and memory are a big concern for my project;
- I am looking to upgrade to Angular 2, so I want to understand if my use of constructors will be problematic or against Angular2 best practices.

Currently I am doing this:

```
angular
    .module('MyConstructorModule', [])
    .service('MyConstructor', MyConstructor);

/* @ngInject */
function MyConstructor($http) {

    var MyConstructor = function(url, getPar){
        this.url = url;
        this.getPar = getPar;
        return this;
    }

    MyConstructor.prototype.getStuff = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: this.url + this.getPar
        });
    }

    return MyConstructor;
}

// Used in functions in which MyConstructor is Injected
new MyConstructor(myurl, myGetParams)
  .getStuff()
  .then(callback);
```

I find this very convenient, but my understanding is that it's not in line with AngularJS logic for services, which are [singletons](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

So, alternatively, I could do this:

```
angular
    .module('MyConstructedObjectModule', [])
    .factory('MyConstructedObject', MyConstructedObjectFactory);

/* @ngInject */
function MyConstructedObjectFactory($http) {

    var constructedObject = {
        init : init,
        getStuff : getStuff,
        vars : {}
    }

    function init(url, getPar) {
        constructedObject.vars.url = url;
        constructedObject.vars.getPar = getPar;
        return constructedObject;
    }

    function getStuff() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: constructedObject.vars.url + constructedObject.vars.getPar
        });
    }
}

// NOT TESTED
// Would be Used in functions in which MyConstructedObject is Injected
var newConstructedObject = _.cloneDeep(MyConstructedObject); // https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#cloneDeep
newConstructedObject
  .init(myurl, myGetParams)
  .getStuff()
  .then(callback);
```

In this way I would be following AngularJS best practices. But then:

- would it be any easier to upgrade to Angular 2?
- would I have any gains or losses in terms of performance or memory usage?

Comment: There's a bunch of things in A1 than may become an obstacle because they aren't possible or implemented differently in A2, you can't know them before comparing them face to face. There's no problem with the fact that the service is a constructor. The service is a singleton, it doesn't matter if it is a function or an object. It is naming that creates a confusion. Outer `MyConstructor` is in fact a factory function, not a constructor. And the service is `factory`, not `service`. It may be just anonymous function that returns real `MyConstructor` class (that's how it would be in A2).

Comment: See [`useFactory` service type](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html#other-provider-configurations)

Comment: There is no 'factory' construct in Angular 2. Service singletons are created wherever they're declared as providers for a component/module, and they're not created the same way as Angular 1- instead of calling a constructor manually, dependencies are injected into constructors by the framework. Bottom line: it will need heavy refactoring when migrating to Angular 2 either way.